# Local Chrome extension write to local txt file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't find how can I read and write in my local chrome extension folder a txt file with jQuery.

I don't have a code for writing to file. Could anybody point to the right direction ? Thanks!

Comment: [This forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/aj4X_sA44JI) answers your question: `Impossible. Chrome's extension API does not allow reading or writing to disk`.

Comment: @andys would this be something you're looking for? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_filesystem